# BASH return to main function

Tags: bash, shell-script, function

I have a BASH script that calls a function, which calls other functions:

```
#!/bin/bash
function foo
{
    function bar
    {
        # do something
    }
    bar
}
foo
```

How can I return from `bar` directly to the main function? The case is that `bar` handles user input and if it receives a negative answer, it must return to the main function, otherwise it has to return to `foo`.

Returning to `foo` is not a problem with a simple `return` statement. For the other, I tried this (which actually works):

```
#!/bin/bash
function foo
{
    function bar
    {
        if [negative] # abstract statement
        then return 1
        else return 0
        fi
    }
    ! bar && return
}
foo
```

But since I have functions like `foo` spread across the whole project (`bar` is defined in a header file), is there a way that only requires modification to `bar`? The project is ~2k lines long and consists of several files, it would be much easier that way if there's a solution.

Comment: I  don't think that this exists. This would be the equvialent of a `goto`, which doesn't exist in bash as far as I know.

Comment: @polym No, BASH doesn't have a `goto` unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no nice way (I am aware of) to do that but if you are willing to pay the price...

Instead of putting the code in functions you can put it in files you source. If the functions need arguments then you have to prepare them with `set`:

```
set -- arg1 arg2 arg3
source ...
```

Three files:

1. testscript.sh

   ```
   #! /bin/bash

   startdir="$PWD"

   echo mainscript

   while true; do
           echo "begin: helper loop"
           source "${startdir}/func_1"
           echo "end: helper loop"
           break
   done

   echo mainscript
   ```
2. func_1

   ```
   echo "begin: func_1"
   source "${startdir}/func_2"
   echo "end: func_1"
   ```
3. func_2

   ```
   echo "begin: func_2"
   echo break from func_2
   break 100
   echo "end: func_2"
   ```

Result:

```
> ./testscript.sh
mainscript
begin: helper loop
begin: func_1
begin: func_2
break from func_2
mainscript
```

Comment: Seems interesting... If I got it right, the main point here is the usage of `break 100`, which returns to the caller **loop**, not the caller **function**.

Comment: @psimon The point is that `break` can skip levels whereas `return` cannot.